# How do I get rid of the errormessage when I use Sublime text 2 in terminal

Tags: command-line, sublime-text

When I open a Java source-code with sublime text the error message keep rolling in the terminal Window:

```
(sublime_text:19271): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 2897 was not found when attempting to remove it.
```

Any solutions? It works but is really annoying.

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution really, but a workaround. Just redirect standard error to `/dev/null` so you don't see it:

```
sublime foo.jar 2>/dev/null
```

To make this simpler, you can convert that to a function. Add these lines to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
sublime(){
    sublime "$@" 2>/dev/null
}
```

That, however, will suppress *all* errors, not only that one. To suppress that one alone, use this instead:

```
sublime(){
    sublime "$@" 2>&1 | grep -v 'GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 2897 was not found when attempting to remove it.'
}
```